# Can casperjs/phantom.js can run on Amazon EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, phantomjs, casperjs

I've managed to build and run scripts on my computer.

What if I want it to work on a server? I'd like to be able to send requests to a server and process them using CasperJS.

I imagine that on a regular web server, such thing is possible.

Is such thing possible on Amazon's EC2?

Is there any other web server hosting solutions that allow such thing?

Answer (score 6):

Today I ran casperjs (and phantomjs) on a fresh Amazon EC2 instance, running Ubuntu 12.04.  Setup was pretty minimal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g phantomjs
sudo npm install -g casperjs
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
```

Worked like a charm.  You don't need to setup a web server.  You just need the command line.

Comment: You can probably even skip the 3rd step `sudo npm install -g phantomjs` because phantomjs is included as a dependency in casperjs modules.

Comment: had to do this: `sudo yum update 
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel 
sudo npm install -g phantomjs 
sudo npm install -g casperjs`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't know about EC2. In general casperjs needs access to the phantomjs.exe.  I see no reason why any server which allows access to the shell would cause you problems.  The real question may be whether or not this will be fast enough for a web application.   Although I'm not really sure what your specific requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on any cloud provider(IAAS: google computeengine, amazon ec2, rackspace ...). 
Please note that some PAAS(appengine) will not allow you to run something like that or it will be a pain and not worth it on some (Heroku...)